# converting timeseries dataframe to be an input of univariate LSTM classifier

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have a standard LSTM NN for classification:

```
n_timesteps = 25 #at each point we look at the last 25 time points
n_features= 1  #each time series is 1d
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And I have a dataframe with the shape `(370 , 675)`
Such that each row is a time series, and each col is a timestamp. (so `df[n,m]` is the value of the m timepoint for the n sample)

To my understanding, in order to train the classifier on this dataframe, I need to first convert it to a 2d array with the shape of `(370*27, 25)` (since 25*27==675), and this should be the input for the model?

So I run:

```
X = df.values.reshape((370*27,25))
model.fit(x = X, y = y)
```

And get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 25]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Where does  25 and 27 come from? You have specified 35 as timesteps in your code, but then 27 and 25? Anyway it can be like this: `X = df.values.reshape((-1,n_timesteps,n_features))`. Note that it should be dividable by 375*675

Comment: @Kaveh Fixed, can you please explain why the -1 is needed?
So, in your proposed solution - in each iteration, the nn will be trained on timewindow of 25 timestamps, each has a single feature , right?

Comment: Since always the first dimension is number of samples: (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features). So a  3d input is needed. By specifying -1 you tell numpy to infer the first dimension by itself and you don't have to compute like (370*675)/(25*1). Since you haven't specified batch size, it considers the default which is 32. So, in each iteration it train on (32,25,1) input. And each epoch is containing of (n_samples/32) steps or iteration.

Comment: @Kaveh My original label vector is also with the shape (1,370). I need to reshape it with accordance to X in order to maintain the correct label per sample. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: If so, then may you have some misunderstandings. You should specify how many samples do you have? 370? If so, then your labels shape (370,1) is ok. and then 675 should be divided to number of features and timesteps. X shape: (370, 25, 27). Otherwise you should provide labels for each sample. May some more explanation about your data structure is needed.

Comment: @Yes, I have 370 timeserieses, each with 675 timestamps, and I want to classify them with timewindows of 25.
When I am trying reshape to (370,25,37) I get an error - So I shoukd I reshape the data to insert it to the model?

Comment: So, each sample (each row) will be 27 samples with 25 timesteps and 1 feature, right? Then X shape: (370*27, 25, 1) is the shape you need. You also have only 370 labels for each row, but after reshape you need 370*27 labels. If all labels of each row is the same then you should repeat each label 25 times to get Y shape (370*25).

Comment: Sorry I dont understand why each row is 27 samples?

Comment: LSTM expects 3D input of shape `[batch, time, features]`, but in this case its [time,features]. Need to add extra dimension to your input `tf.expand_dims(input, axis=0)`. Thanks!